# ListView not showing items on a smaller screen

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, screen-size

I had an emulator with a larger screen and it all works well. `ListView` shows everything perfectly normal so its not in the java code. I have tried testing it now on a 3.2 screen and `ListView` doesn't show anything. I tried with a smaller screen (3.2) emulator and it also didn't show anything so I guess this has something to do with they layout.

My listview.xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row xml file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your layout imo.

Comment: @Aerilys that's what I think too. But everything works on a larger screen so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to wrap_content for ListView.

Comment: Actually, layout_height can be wrap_content. About layout_width it's true.

Comment: Thank you! Very important thing I did not know. I actually watched this, but did not mentioned it earlier.

Comment: I understand but this didn't solve my problem, I edited my xmls

Comment: @DoctororDrive Any other suggestion people?

Comment: Maybe you should show us some more code, because layout looks good.